# Custom HTML attribute in <table> generated by <p:dataTable>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, passthrough-attributes

I have a Primefaces Datatable component and I need to put a custom attribute on it. I tried with `<f:passThroughAttribute name="customP" value="1" />` but when it renders it puts the attributes into a wrapper div, insted of the `<table>` tag.

Is there a way to send that custom attribute like this `<table customP="1">`

Comment: Did you try: `<html ... xmlns:pass="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
... <h:inputText ... pass:customP="1" />`?

Comment: Yes, had the same result, Primefaces sends the value to the wrapper DIV tag.

Comment: So, what is the purpose of using that custom `attribute`? If it is intended for the `CSS` or `jQuery` selector, then you can use even it is on the container `div`.

Comment: QA was asking for it, I finally solved it adding a class with tableStyleClass.

Comment: @parkashkumar is right. Maybe the QA department should take a css selector lesson...